# Postgres RDS - massive reduction in histogram performance on identical data and indexes

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

On putting a system we're developing up to a staging server backed by Amazon RDS (postgres), we're finding one query running on identical data with identical indexes is running nearly 1000 time slower on RDS than locally.

```
SELECT cast(min(price_latest) as bigint) as minprice,cast(max(price_latest) as bigint) as maxprice, COUNT(*), histogram(cast(price_latest as bigint), 0, 10000000, 1000) FROM "locations" WHERE (ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((1.734671 52.591183, 1.744188 52.573059, 1.729994 52.562677, 1.742489 52.528631, .... , 1.734671 52.591183)))'),lonlat))
```

locally it is running in the 100-200ms range (which is acceptable), and on the RDS it's taking around 80 seconds to return the same result...

the local EXPLAIN ANALYSE on the query gives:

```
Aggregate  (cost=67403.05..67403.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=110.657..110.657 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on locations  (cost=686.61..66488.76 rows=3483 width=8) (actual time=6.329..60.381 rows=8180 loops=1)
    Recheck Cond: ('010600000001 (...)
    Filter: (is_primary AND (live = 1) AND ((buy_or_rent)::text = 'buy'::text) AND _st_contains('010600000001 (...)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 12232
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_lonlat  (cost=0.00..685.74 rows=21005 width=0) (actual time=5.600..5.600 rows=21646 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ('010600000001 (...)
Total runtime: 111.027 ms
```

Where the RDS remote version gives:

```
Aggregate  (cost=67462.71..67462.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=107304.702..107304.702 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on locations  (cost=826.47..66578.87 rows=3367 width=8) (actual time=5000.747..107178.185 rows=8180 loops=1)
    Recheck Cond: ('010600000001 (...)
    Filter: (is_primary AND (live = 1) AND ((buy_or_rent)::text = 'buy'::text) AND _st_contains('010600000001 (...)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 13646
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_lonlat  (cost=0.00..825.62 rows=23095 width=0) (actual time=4912.543..4912.543 rows=21826 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ('010600000001 (...)
Total runtime: 107326.975 ms
```

This is the histogram function we are using: [postgres function](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Histogram)

It seem they (local macbook machine and RDS) are both attacking the query the same way - so why the discrepancy? - the result is returned on one line, so I don't think it's network latency.

Comment: Usual suspects: differences in 0) cache warming 1) row versions 2) server tuning 3) machine speed. Note: always add `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` to your question.

Comment: Thanks - let me run EXPLAIN ANALYSE and update my question..

Comment: Indeed, for small result sets, network lantency should not be a factor. The estimates look very similar (and I expect the results form `explain analyse` to be similar, too.), so "wrong or missing statistics" should not be a factor. The Postgres version *could* be a factor, though.

Comment: i've updated with explain analyse - interested to hear what you think...

Comment: The actual execution plan is the same. Cost differs a little because of different amount of rows in tables. You need to investigate latencies between you and the server, it's capacity and current usage - this may be causing what you're experiencing. There may also be locks. On localhost you don't experience such things.

Comment: No conclusion. Either machine speed  , or memory pressure (RDS is a VM, isn't it?) or row versions. Does VACUUM run frequently on the RDS instance? Oh, and I should have asked you to also include the `buffers=true)` to the explain. Sorry.

Comment: hmmm - i've just seen that we're casting a column to a different data-type for the purpose of the histogram generation. cast(min(price_latest) as bigint) - i'm guessing that's going to need some memory... which we don't have a lot of on the RDS instance...

Comment: I dont know what histogram() does, but, I presume it will need some memory for the ... histogram ...